# ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am working on PIG programming,

`grunt> dividends = load 'NYSE_dividends' as>> (exchange:chararray, symbol:chararray, date:chararray, dividend:float);`

`grunt> LIMIT dividends 10;`

But i am not sure why i getting this error :

`[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "LIMIT "" at line 3, column 1.`

My data link is [Data Link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alanfgates/programmingpig/7de981e4766cbaa37b6fa60d557ad74fb120434b/data/NYSE_dividends)

Please help me to find out the issue!!!

Comment: I used limit because when i will use `DUMP dividends` then i want it to show only 10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you didn't assign the output relation. Can you change like this?

```
grunt> result = LIMIT dividends 10;
grunt> DUMP result;
```